# Can we have "don't abuse the spam/offensive flag" options on the decline flag dialog

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Following on from my [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189135/can-we-have-an-option-to-ban-someone-from-using-the-offensive-and-or-spam-flags) I have a request that specific, predefined "please don't abuse the spam/offensive flag" options be added to the moderator decline flag dialog.

This would be useful whether or not that feature is implemented or not and would make the declining of bad spam/offensive flags that much easier.

It would also be an important first step on that process.

Comment: Frankly I think this is subsumed by "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - I thought that at first, but it's slightly more specific because of the seriousness of the flag.

Comment: I agree with BoltClock, I've been using that response when declining these. Quite frankly, I found that almost no one read any of the custom decline reasons I gave for these, so I don't know that a different reason would make much of a difference.