# Don't send a notification if you cast the final vote to reopen your own question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, vote-to-reopen

Yesterday, my question [Is Stack Exchange staff removing GoFundMe links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339235/295232) was reopened. As of [a few weeks ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336960/295232), this results in an inbox notification (see below). However, [I (the author) cast the final vote to reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/339235/revisions), which makes the notification pointless or even worse:  noise. If you comment on your own post, you don't get a notification either.

Can the functionality be improved such that this doesn't happen anymore?

[image]

(I reopened the question using a dupehammer; it could be that the code just didn't account for this particular edge case but otherwise works fine.)

Comment: I hate it when websites do this. Even worse when it's an email. "Hey F1Krazy, F1Krazy just did X!" Yes, I *know* I did that.

Comment: This definitely is an edge case. Since when you would do a regular vote to re-open you don't know if it will be successful, besides when you cast the 5th and binding reopen vote. Which would be a second edge case.

Comment: @Luuklag I was pretty aware that my dupehammer would be in effect. Moreover, if you cast the final reopen vote, the page is *reloaded* so you immediately see the effect. I think I got the notification a short while later, after I navigated away.

Comment: I wonder if the same thing happens when you post the 5th re-open vote on one of your own questions then.

Comment: Hooray! Blimey that's chummy. Also "anyone can answer it now" is probably not true...

Comment: It’s to prevent abuse. People are more likely to reopen their own posts illegitimately. If you know you’re going to have to suffer a notification you’ll think twice before doing it.

Answer (score 6):

This will be fixed in the next build.

When a question is reopened, we now check if the last user to vote to reopen was the post owner and if so suppress the notification.