# Why do I get a "hooray, your question was reopened" message when the question seem not to have been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, notifications, global-inbox, reopened-questions

I received today for [one of my questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77887/does-the-catholic-church-have-a-contingency-plan-for-the-case-that-the-pope-and) the following Inbox message:

[image: Hooray, this question was reopened! Anyone can answer it now]

I am surprised because:

- I didn't even know the question was closed (I neither saw any counter on the close flag, nor the `[closed]` suffix in the question title)
- this is the first time I get such a message, despite having had questions closed and reopened in the past

Comment: You could check the timeline of your question if it was closed at a point.

Comment: The timeline shows it was closed: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/77887/timeline you can find the timeline by pressing the clock symbol left of the post, under the voting buttons.

Comment: There is no notification when it's closed due to "Do not notify about bad things" policy which is still mostly in place.

Comment: Thanks everyone - the message is something relatively new (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336960/256398) and I apparently did not have any questions closed and reopened in the meantime. I do not understand, however, why the `[closed]` message was not appended to the title (I checked the question a few times a day so i would not have missed it, especially that there were discussions in the comments about not closing it)

Comment: @WoJ you should get notifications of comments being posted on your question IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [timeline](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/77887/timeline) of the post shows it was indeed closed and then reopened:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that the timeline covers these events (and it is logical that it does, I am not sure why I thought that it was only for edits).

Comment: @WoJ - When a question is closed or reopened a new revision is created and viewable in the edit history and timeline.